# Rails, given an object, how can I find the 2nd item? With the possibility there is not 2nd item

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to be able to do: @p = Project.apps & get the 2nd item in the list, that's the only object.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If `@p` is an array, you can attempt to fetch the second object (the one at index 1) and return nil if it doesn't exist by doing `@p.fetch(1, nil)`. You can change `nil` to whatever you want the default to be (that is, what `fetch` should return if the index doesn't exist).

Comment: What about offset, how do use that in activerecord?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could do @p.second. If second is nil, it will return nil, otherwise the object.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the secound object use limit and offset (LIMIT X,Y in SQL)

```
@p=Project.apps.limit(1).offset(1) if Project.apps.count > 1
```

Otherwise you can also use @p.secound or @p[1].